# Dynamic click event not firing

Tags: jquery-mobile, dynamic, onclick

I have a jQuery mobile page with a number of images I'm using as buttons.

When the page initially loads, all of the images have a class of 'inactive'.
If I click 1 of the buttons, its class is changed to 'active' and all of the other buttons are changed from 'inactive' to 'disabled'. If I navigate away from the page and navigate straight back, the 1 image still has a class of 'active', and the rest still have a class of 'disabled'.

When I click the active button it changes class from 'active' to 'inactive', and all of the other buttons change class from 'disabled' to 'inactive'.
This allows me to choose another button to be the active one.

when I click one of the buttons that was previously disabled but is now inactive, the click event doesn't fire. It's as though it thinks the class is still disabled as it was when the page initially loaded. I've checked using Firebug in Firefox and the class is correctly set as inactive, but it's still behaving as though the class is disabled.

Here's my jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.inactive, .active').on("click", function(){
    // Toggle active/inactive class
    $(this).toggleClass("active inactive");

    // Disable if 1 active button, else inactive
    if($('.active').length == 1) {
      $('.inactive').toggleClass("inactive disabled");
    } else {
      $('.disabled').toggleClass("disabled inactive");
    }
  });

});
```

And the HTML buttons:

```
<a class="button inactive"></a><br />
<a class="button inactive"></a><br />
<a class="button inactive"></a><br />
<a class="button inactive"></a><br />
<a class="button inactive"></a><br />
<a class="button inactive"></a>
```

And the classes:

```
.button {
  background:url("../images/compare.png") no-repeat;
  width: 18px;
  height:18px
}
.active {
  background-position: 0 -18px;
  cursor:pointer
}
.inactive {
  background-position: 0 0;
  cursor:pointer
}
.disabled {
  background-position: 0 -36px;
  cursor:default
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys, I've figured this out.

When I change the class from disabled to inactive, the click handler doesn't get attached to the 'new' inactive buttons automatically.

I've added a new class 'mybutton' to all the buttons (so an active button would be class="mybutton active" for example), then looked for that class in the click handler so even the disabled buttons will run through the code.

Here's my new code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  $('.mybutton').on("click", function(){
    if($(this).hasClass("inactive") || $(this).hasClass("active")) {
      $(this).toggleClass("active inactive");
    }

    // Disable if 1 active button, else inactive
    if($('.active').length == 1) {
      $('.inactive').toggleClass("inactive disabled");
    } else {
      $('.disabled').toggleClass("disabled inactive");
    }
  });

});
```

I had to wrap the $(this).toggleClass("active inactive"); statement in an if statement which has me puzzled.

Without the if statement, clicking a disabled button would turn it to active.
Why would this happen? And why does wrapping the button in an if statement fix it when it's just checking for the same classes as the toggle?